# Extending the default behaviour of React.FC in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

So I have a tutorial that uses the below code in Nextjs and I plan on moving it from javascript to typescript. I'm new to typescript, So I've tried most of the articles I've seen but extending the default React.FC seems not to work.

```
function Explore() {
  return <p className="p-4">Explore</p>;
}

Explore.headerTitle = "Search";

export default Explore;
```

My Component

```
const Home: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>Home / Twitter</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>

            <div>
                <p>Hello </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
Home.headerTitle = "Search";
```

My Interface

```
export interface HeaderTitle extends React.FunctionComponent {
    headerTitle: string;
}
```

I would like to add a method to my Functional component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declare your interface separately from `React.FunctionComponent` (for reusability):

```
export interface WithHeaderTitle {
   static headerTitle?: string;
}
```

And then in your component code, import the interface and use it like this:

```
const Home: React.FunctionComponent & WithHeaderTitle = () => { ... }
```

The keyword here is "Intersection Types". You could read more about it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types

Comment: I made a mistake in my code, I used the "&&" instead of "&".  Thanks.

I used your solution although, I removed the static declaration